# asp.net identity 2.0 Facebook public_profile not returning fields

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use Facebook as an external login provider with Asp.net Identity 2.0. I have my Facebook Authentication options in Startup.Auth configured like:

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[OneStepCloserTo.Web.Models.Constants.FacebookClientIdKey],
            AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[OneStepCloserTo.Web.Models.Constants.FacebookClientSecretKey]
        };

        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_friends");
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_hometown");
```

The email scope works because I can see my email address in the claims returned. However, none of the [public_profile fields listed here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-public-profile) are returned. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly get Facebook profile information from claims added through facebookOptions scope. You have to add scopes as you did in your sample and use FacebookClient.

Try using FacebookClient

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> FacebookInfo()
{
    var claimsforUser = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var access_token = claimsforUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "FacebookAccessToken").Value;
    var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);
    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me/friends");
    var friendsList = newList<FacebookViewModel>();
    foreach (dynamic friend in myInfo.data)
    {
        friendsList.Add(newFacebookViewModel()
           {
               Name = friend.name,
               ImageURL = @"https://graph.facebook.com/" + friend.id + "/picture?type=large"
           });
    }

    return View(friendsList);
} 


  public class FacebookViewModel
  {
       [Required]
       [Display(Name = "Friend's name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string ImageURL { get; set; }
  }
```

[Refer to this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it, see

```
var fbOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
        fbOptions.AppId = ...
        fbOptions.AppSecret = ...
        fbOptions.Fields.Add("email"); 
        fbOptions.Fields.Add("first_name");
        fbOptions.Fields.Add("last_name"); 
        fbOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
        fbOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        fbOptions.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
            {
                JToken value;
                if (context.User.TryGetValue("first_name", out value))
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FacebookFirstName", value.ToString()));
                if (context.User.TryGetValue("last_name", out value))
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FacebookLastName", value.ToString()));
            }
        };
```